# Polynomial in a $2$-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, polynomials, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I am reading about the problem of moments and get some troubles in they way one defines the measure on some $k$-dimensional Euclidean space by polynomial. Could you please help me?

More precisely, I am reading the article "The Problem of Moments", written by Shohat in 1943. In this article, the author let $R$  be a $2$ - dimensional vector space.
The author also put $P (u,v)$ as any polynomial in $u,v \in R$.
$$P(u,v) = \sum_{i,j} x_iy_j u^i v^j,$$
where $x_i, y_j$ are real or complex - valued constants.

After that, the author introduced the functional $\mu (P) = \sum_{i,j} \mu_{i,j} x_i y_j$.

So, my questions are the following.

1. How can we define $u^i, v^j$ in $R$, where $u$ and $v$ are some
   vectors in $R$?
2. What is the definition of a polynomial in a $2$-dimensional vector
   space? I tried to search on the internet, however, no useful
   material has been found.
3. What is $\mu_{ij}$ in his formula?

Comment: $u,v$ are real numbers. You said yourself that $u,v \in R$.  He just means a polynomial in two variables.  The formula for $P(u,v)$ is the definition.  The $\mu_{i,j}$ are just real numbers in the formula you have given.  They may mean something more specific in the paper.

Comment: If $u$ is a vector of length 2, how to define the powers $u^i$?

Comment: @Wuestenfux It looks like the superscripted $i$ and $j$ are being used to represent contravariant indices (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors). So this may be related to tensor analysis.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry, I confused a little bit about this since the hypothesis "$R$ is a 2-dimensional Euclidean space". So, from my point of view, $u$ and $v$ should be some vectors with 2 entries.

Comment: How do you reconcile that with the statement $u,v \in R$?

Comment: I think that the assumption has been mentioned in the sentence "The author also put $P(u,v)$ as any polynomial in $u,v∈R$.